# I want to write a code that can take two numbers and create a txt file between those numbers in decreasing order

Tags: python

here is the code

```
import os
myfile  = ('filename.txt' ,'wb')

a = int(input('integer a: '))
b = int(input('integer b: '))

def cal(a,b):
    while a>b:
        a = a-1
        print a

c = str(cal(a,b))
print c

myfile.writelines(c)
```

I am getting only last word written in file.  please someone help me.

Comment: You don't return anything from your `cal` function.

Comment: add `return a` in cal() last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you returned a at the end of your cal function you would just get one number being written. You can do the whole thing a lot easier by using a range and converting it to a list, then joining that list with a space

```
import os
smallNum= int(input('smaller integer a: '))
bigNum= int(input('bigger integer b: '))

with open('filename.txt' ,'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write(" ".join([str(x) for x in list(range(smallNum+1,bigNum))]))
```

This line of code creates a range of all the numbers in between your two nums:

```
range(bigNum+1,smallNum)
```

Then convert to a list (of ints)

```
list(range(bigNum+1,smallNum))
```

Then convert that to a list of strings with a list comprehension

```
 [str(x) for x in list(range(bigNum+1,smallNum))]
```

Finally join each item in the list with a space

```
 " ".join([str(x) for x in list(range(bigNum+1,smallNum))])
```

## A solution that doesn't use list comprehensions / .join / context managers

```
import os
smallNum = int(input('smaller integer a: '))
bigNum = int(input('bigger integer b: '))

writeString = "" #string to write to file later

for currentNum in range(smallNum+1, bigNum): #non-inclusive range of numbers
    strNum = str(currentNum) #convert to string
    writeString += strNum + " " #add the number and a space to the string

file = open("filename.txt", "w")
file.write(writeString)
file.close()
```

Comment: The original question does look horribly like a manufactured un-realistic problem written by a college teacher/professor for a beginners class. My guess is that professor would defintely not like your submission (even through it is right and probably the best answer) - they wouldn't like because a) It is not anything that the course has covered (list comprehensions, context managers etc), and the professor might not even understand it themselves.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Alright I've edited the question to include a more simplified way of doing it. Just for fun I benchmarked the two and for numbers 10-999999 the first solution takes 0.3 seconds and the other one takes 1.8 seconds! Probably all that string concatenation. My file ended up being 6.57 MB too

Comment: thanks guys.  :) it took me a lot time to figure out that loop was ending before writing anything to file.

Comment: @Racialz - looks good - in a horrible basic, first lession type of way. Hopefully the proffessor explains the right way to do things soon. I wonder if it might be quicker to write to the file each time round the loop - rather than string concats - it seems that object creation is slowish.

Comment: actually I am learning on my own.  so things are messy. so can you guide me with 'right ways' you are talking about.